# find friends friend to suggest mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to add feature of find friends friend to suggest

My table is like :

[image]

here whenever any two user becomes friend their combination will be in user2_id,user1_id

Now when I have fire query to find suggest friend like:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(user2_id,',',user1_id)) FROM `friends` WHERE user1_id = 78 OR user2_id = 78
```

the result is : `79,78,6,78`
which is wrong

so how to find the friend's friend list which is not in my account?

Comment: What is the expected outcome?

Comment: it should be comma separated id which is not in my list, means 79,6